# yii2 how to keep form data in case of model->save fails

Tags: view, yii2, save, form-fields

I loose my form data, if model->save function fails. My form is based on two different models, because they are related to each other. The controller function is actionCreate.

```
 public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Model1();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        //try to save Model1 in the first step
        $transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
        try {
            $model->save();
            $new_model1_id = $model->id; //id of new inserted company
            // write in model2 second step
            $model2 = new Model2();
            $model2->example1 = $example1;
            $model2->example2 = $example2;
            if ($model2->save()) {
                $transaction->commit();
                return $this->redirect(['index']);
            } else {
                $transaction->rollBack();
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Error!');
                //return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer ?: Yii::$app->homeUrl);// return to last page
                return $this->goBack((!empty(Yii::$app->request->referrer) ? Yii::$app->request->referrer : null));
            };
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $transaction->rollBack();
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Error!');
            //return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer ?: Yii::$app->homeUrl);// return to last page
            return $this->goBack((!empty(Yii::$app->request->referrer) ? Yii::$app->request->referrer : null));
        }
    }
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);

}
```

I'am trying to go back to the last page, when model saving has error.:

```
return $this->goBack((!empty(Yii::$app->request->referrer) ? Yii::$app->request->referrer : null));
```

But this is not working. How can I stay on the page respectively coming back to the page without loosing all the existing form entries?

Comment: Just render the page again, don't use `goBack()` or any redirect. Allow your code to get to line with `return $this->render(...`.

Comment: You are right! Of course, that would be the right approach! It seems that I got lost in deep thoughts! Thx

Answer (score 0):

According to the recommendation of Yupic,..Just render the page again, don't use goBack() or any redirect. Allow your code to get to line with return $this->render(...